# Unable to compile class for JSP , jstl taglib

Tags: javascript, java, spring, jsp, servlets

when i adding the jstl/core taglib, jsp unable to compile

and when i remove the my java script code, jsp compiled as well

jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="true"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c"  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/mvc-test/static/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" ></script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" >

<meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

<title>main page</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function getMetaContentByName(name, content) {
    var content = (content == null) ? 'content' : content;
    return document.querySelector("meta[name='" + name + "']").getAttribute(content);
}

    function success() {
        alert("SUCCESS");
    }

    function error() {
        alert("error");
    }

    function removeEntity(id) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "DELETE",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/mvc-test/rest/user/delete/"+id,
            dataType : 'json',
            success : success,
            error : error
        });
        console.log(sd);
    }
    function searchEntity(id,userName, family) {
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            contentType : "application/json",
            url : "http://localhost:8080/mvc-test/rest/user/searchAll?pageNumber=1&pageSize=2&&orderBy=userName asc",
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': getMetaContentByName('_csrf')},
            data : JSON.stringify({
                "id":id,
                "userName" : userName,
                "familyName" : family
            }),
            dataType : 'json',
            success : success,
            error : error
        });
    }
    </script>


</head>
<body>
        <input value="searchAll" type="button" onclick="searchEntity(-1,'','r')" />
        <input value="login" type="button" onclick="logined('rahmat','rahmat')" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

some dependency i used for jsp

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
.
.
.


root cause

java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
org.gjt.xpp.impl.tokenizer.Tokenizer.next(Tokenizer.java:1274)
org.gjt.xpp.impl.pullparser.PullParser.next(PullParser.java:392)
org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.parseSubTree(Driver.java:415)
org.gjt.xpp.sax2.Driver.parse(Driver.java:310)
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:392)
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:195)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlBaseTLV.validate(JstlBaseTLV.java:165)
org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV.validate(JstlCoreTLV.java:105)
.
.
.

org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
```

use tomcat 8.0.30
and java 1.8.0_45

tnx for help

Comment: I see nothing suspicious in your JSP code. You say, when you remove the JS code between `<script ...>` and `</script>`, the page gets compiled correctly? Well, maybe try to remove just parts of that code (starting from whole functions, down to the particular lines of code), to identify, which part(s) are causing the problem.

Comment: before  i adding the jstl/core taglib was correct, i think this taglib caused error

Comment: That is quite possible, but you need to identify, with which line of the code is the taglib getting in conflict.

Comment: if i remove one of functions ,jsp compiled well

Comment: i think one or more library need to add my project, or tomcat and java has problem ------ please help

Comment: @alireza i had the same problem, so create js file and copy pist js code and after add link in your html file